# Stateless Session Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, java-ee-5, stateless-session-bean

Do I package a stateless session bean in a war file or a ear file for deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Neither nor. EJBs belong in standard JAR files (with a META-INF/ejb-jar.xml). In order to use EJBs from a WAR you pack these two archives in an EAR.

Since this is not really convenient it's possible since EJB 3.1 to package EJBs in the WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Stateless Session Beans (SLSB) are packaged in an EJB-JAR (which is a regular JAR file) including or not an optional deployment descriptor. EJB-JARs and WARs are assembled in an EAR for deployment.

See this article by Debu Panda and Rezza Rahmann (which is actually an extract from the excellent *EJB 3 in Action*):

- [Packaging EJB 3 Applications](http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3670496_2/Packaging-EJB-3-Applications.htm)

Answer (score 0):

With EJB 3.1/Java EE 6 you don't need EAR files any more, you can also put your session beans directly in a WAR file (as a separate .class file in WEB-INF/classes, or inside a JAR file within the WAR file's WEB-INF/lib directory). See e.g. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part3.html#simpack